# The second argument of Ecto.Query.from/2

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I encountered a weird error while I was trying construct a query using [Ecto.Query.from/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#from/2).
Please see the code below:

```
iex(24)> import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 2]
nil
iex(25)> from User, limit: 1 # valid
#Ecto.Query<from u in Jcb.User, limit: 1>

iex(26)> opts = [limit: 1]
[limit: 1]
iex(27)> Keyword.keyword? opts
true

iex(28)> from user, opts
** (ArgumentError) second argument to `from` must be a keyword list
    (ecto) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.from/2
           iex:28: (file)
```

I found the source code [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/query.ex#L280-L282), but I wasn't sure it's bug or not. Please help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It has something to do with elixir [macros](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html)

> That’s because the arguments to a function call are evaluated before calling the function. However, macros do not evaluate their arguments. Instead, they receive the arguments as quoted expressions which are then transformed into other quoted expressions.

```
defmodule Mod do
  defmacro test_macro(kw \\ []) do
    IO.puts inspect(kw)
    IO.puts Keyword.keyword?(kw)
    quote do
      Keyword.keyword?(unquote(kw))
    end
  end
end

> import Mod

> test_macro []
[]
true
true


> kw = []
> test_macro kw
{:kw, [line: 63], nil}
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for the problem could be in this case:

```
limit = 1
from User, limit: ^limit
```

In the case no limit is desired `limit` can be set to `nil`:

```
limit = nil
from User, limit: ^limit  # unlimited results (at least with postgresql)
```